# How to fetch the latest records using find_one in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have an existing program where I'm trying to fetch last inserted document which matches the key `aws_account_id` using `find_one` in pymongo.

I'm using this query to perform the fetching:

```
report = securitydb.scout.find_one({'aws_account_id': aws_account.account_number})
```

But this query returns a wrong document. The image below demonstrates the expected result and the wrong one that I'm getting.

[image]

In the image, both documents have the same aws_account_id but the red one is inserted last. So the expected result is the red marked document but it pulls the yellow marked document.

I'm not sure if I need to use sorting or things like that. I got some solution but those are based on pure mongo query. I need help doing this with pymongo.

Thanks In Advance,
Robin

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `sort` in the `*args` for [`find_one()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)

```
report = securitydb.scout.find_one(
  {'aws_account_id': aws_account.account_number},
  sort=[( '_id', pymongo.DESCENDING )]
)
```

Using `_id` here because the `ObjectId` values are always going to "increase" as they are added, but anything else like a "date" which also indicates the "latest" can be used as long as it's in the `DESCENDING` sort order, which means "latest" is on the "top" of the results.

You can `import pymongo` if you didn't already do that and use the `pymongo.DESCENDING` token, or just `-1` to indicate "descending" order. The former probably makes much clearer code.

Also note the "ordered dict" since the order of keys for "sorting" is usually important, or at least if you want to sort on the combination of more than one key.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your detailed answer. It worked!!

Comment: Anyone know how well the time complexity of this solution scales with respect to the number of documents stored? In other words how much will this solution become slower as the number of documents stored increases?

Comment: It's probably much faster than sending a large quantity of unnecessary data over the wire if that's what you are concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for obtaining the last record:

```
report = securitydb.scout.find_one({'aws_account_id':aws_account.account_number},
                                   sort=[('$natural', -1)])
```